# Why I can't assign , &client object created by new to unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I know there are other ways to do this. But I decide to experiment this:

```
    unique_ptr<int> pi;
    pi = std::move(new int);
```

When I compile this code, the compiler gives an error. why?

Comment: Well, what is the error? And why are you `std::move`ing a pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `unique_ptr` doesn't have "assign a raw pointer" functionality with its [`operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D).
This is *probably* to avoid people making mistakes.

(By the way, your `std::move` does nothing.)

You can use the constructor:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> pi(new int);
```

or `std::make_unique`:

```
auto pi = std::make_unique<int>();
```

or, to assign later, [`reset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset):

```
std::unique_ptr<int> pi;
pi.reset(new int);
```